# Why can't i bring my img to the foreground in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm currently making a website in React and am using sytled-components. I created a styled-component of an image, but i can't bring it to the foreground for some reason.
index.tsx

```
import {
  Nav,
  NavLink,
  Bars,
  NavMenu,
  NavBtn,
  NavBtnLink,
  NavImg,
} from "./NavbarElements";

import NameLogo from "../../images/logo.svg"

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
        <NavLink to="/">
          <NavImg src={NameLogo} z-index="-1" alt="logo" />
        </NavLink>
        <Bars />
        <NavMenu>
          <NavLink to="/AboutMe">
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/Home">Services</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/Home">Contact Us</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/Home">Sign Up</NavLink>
          {/* Second Nav */}
          {/* <NavBtnLink to='/sign-in'>Sign In</NavBtnLink> */}
        </NavMenu>
        <NavBtn>
          <NavBtnLink to="/signin">Sign In</NavBtnLink>
        </NavBtn>
      </Nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

navbarelements.tsx

```
import { NavLink as Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const NavImg = styled.img`
  height: 10rem;
  position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1:
`;

export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem calc((100vw - 1000px) / 2);

  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-start; */
`;

export const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.active {
    color: #15cdfc;
  }
`;

export const Bars = styled(FaBars)`
  display: none;
  color: #fff;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 75%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

export const NavMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: -24px;

  /* Second Nav */
  /* margin-right: 24px; */

  /* Third Nav */
  /* width: 100vw;
  white-space: nowrap; */

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 24px;

  /* Third Nav */
  /* justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100vw; */

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavBtnLink = styled(Link)`
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #256ce1;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;

  /* Second Nav */
  margin-left: 24px;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    color: #010606;
  }
`;
```

Site currently looks like this(top left black block is image that is hidden behind navbar):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uay4k.png

Comment: Set z-index way higher.

Comment: I'm' afraid that hasn't helped, as i've already set it to 100 or even 1000 once. It didn't make any difference.